# What is the persistance in Laravel sentry?

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm upgrading laravel version from 4.2 to 5.5.
I saw it library called 'Sentry' doesn't support at Laravel Ver 5.5.
I want to Change Sentry used Ver4.2 to Sentinel which support Ver 5.5.
So, I study Project which use library called 'cartalyst/Sentry' now.
But, I don't know **persistance** or **Persist** of Sentry.

What is the **persistance**?
Also, Is it OK not to use about persistance?

Somebody, Help me!